# New bulk action to resend welcome emails

Tags: plugins, actions

I have added a new custom bulk action to the user listing page called Resend Welcome Email, it is showing and running. 
What I'm looking to do is fire the [Resend Welcome Email](https://wordpress.org/plugins/resend-welcome-email/) plugin's action. I'm struggling to implement this... I have tried to use the add_action call of:

```
add_action ( 'resend_welcome_email', 20, $user );
```

But nothing seems to happen. It is possible to fire a plugin's action via this method? Is that how add_action works?

What I'm looking to do is [talked about here](https://github.com/atwellpub/resend-welcome-email/issues/6) but I can't figure out how to action what the plugin author is talking about.

Thanks,
Adam

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think the plugin is helpful for your case, and you can just call the WordPress API yourself directly:

```
wp_new_user_notification( $user_id, null, 'both' );
```

This is all the plugin does: get's the user ID from request parameters, verifies the user exists and then calls [wp_new_user_notifications](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_new_user_notification/) ([see plugin code here](https://github.com/atwellpub/resend-welcome-email/blob/1.1.0/resend-welcome-email.php#L153)).